# Looping through associated data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am feeling my way through CakePHP, trying to replicate what I can already do in vanilla PHP.

I have 2 tables, `events` and `eventlist`. `events` contains general information about an event. `eventlist` contains information that appears as a bullet-pointed list on each event page.

`eventlist` consists of an id, an event_id which links each entry to the relevant event in the `event` table, and a string that is displayed on the page. In vanilla PHP, I would simply `SELECT list_info FROM eventlist WHERE event_id = 1` or whatever, and loop through the resulting array.

However, I have no idea where to start with this in CakePHP, and I'm not sure how i'd search for it to find out.

I have already created an association between the two tables:

```
class Event extends AppModel{

    public $hasMany = array(
        'EventList'
        );

}
```

class EventList extends AppModel{

```
public $useTable = 'eventlist';

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Event'
);
```

}

And I have a simple view set up for `Event`:

```
<h2><?php echo $event['Event']['event_name'] ?></h2>

<p><?php echo $event['Event']['event_description']?></p>

<h3>£<?php echo $event['Event']['event_cost']?></p>
```

But now I have no idea what to do - I am new to CakePHP and MVC as a whole. I assume I need to do something in `EventListController` to load the data into an array. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the relationships that you have setup should return the associated data when you query for an event.  There are a number of ways to get the data in a displayable format, such as using HTML helper to output an (un)ordered list.  But, the example below should help.

Also, a quick way to debug the results from finding a record in your controller is to use `pr` (an alias for print_r) like `pr($event);exit;`.  There are other ways to debug too, but this is a quick and dirty method if you're working locally.

#### Controller

```
$event = $this->Event->findById(`event_id`);
$this->set(compact('event'));
```

#### View

```
<h2><?php echo $event['Event']['event_name'] ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $event['Event']['event_description']?></p>
<p>£<?php echo $event['Event']['event_cost']?></p>
<!-- Output each list item in a paragraph -->
<p>
    <?php foreach($event['EventList'] as $listItem:
       echo $listItem['ListItemColumn'];
    endforeach; ?>
</p>
```

Again...many many ways to get and output this data, but the long and short is that the returned results should have an array key `Event` and an array key `EventList` with the data from each table stored within those keys.

Comment: I knew it would be simple, but it's only simple if you know the syntax :) Thanks.

Comment: A supplementary question: I can output the `EventList` in an underordered list thuswise: `echo $this->Html->nestedList($listItem);` but this outputs _all_ of the table, including the keys. How can I just output the string column (`event_list`) into my list?

Comment: That can be handled in a number of ways too.  The easiest might be to set the `fields` parameter in your query to return `id` and `name` of the EventList object.  Then, use the HTML Helper to output the list like $this->Html->list($event['EventList']);  Or, you could query for the event list separately in your controller as a list, and use the HTML helper: `$eventList = $this->Event->EventList->find('list', ['conditions' => ['event_id' => $event_id]]);`

Comment: In the first example, I assume I'm setting that in my `EventListController`? which is empty at the moment (apart from the class declaration).